regression paradox
I have to do a binary logistic regression with two dichotomous independent variables.
I found myself faced with a paradox that I don't know how to handle.
In the complete database I have 21 (5.6%) deceased patients on 377 patient with volo_1=1 and 86 (3.1%) dead patients on 2766 patients with volo_1=0 and OR 1.84 for volo_1 1vs 0 predicting dead 1 vs 0.
Thus the OR for volo_1 1 vs 0 predicting dead 1 vs 0 is >0 and the dead patients with volo_1=0 fewer than the dead patients with volo_1=1.
If I subsed the database for a dichotomous variable (RTS_cat2) I have two new databases where the OR for volo_1 1 vs 0 predicting dead 1 vs 0 is <0 and the dead patients with volo_1=0 more numerous than the dead patients with volo_1=1.
How can it be?
How can I handle this?
here is my data with problems:
> x <- xtabs(~dead + interaction(volo_1, RTS_cat2), data = db)
> x
     interaction(volo_1, RTS_cat2)
dead  0.0  1.0  0.1  1.1
    0 2485  283  195   73
    1   12    1   74   20

> table(db$dead, db$volo_1)
   
       0    1
  0 2680  356
  1   86   21

> full.model <- glm(dead ~ volo_1    , data = db,family=binomial())
> logistic.display(full.model)

Logistic regression predicting dead 1 vs 0
 
               OR(95%CI)      P(Wald's test) P(LR-test)
volo_1: 1 vs 0 1.84 (1.13,3)  0.015          0.021     
                                                       
Log-likelihood = -464.1848
No. of observations = 3143
AIC value = 932.3696

> full.model <- glm(morto ~ volo_1 +  RTS_cat2    , data = db,family=binomial())
> logistic.display(full.model)

Logistic regression predicting morto 
 
                 crude OR(95%CI)       adj. OR(95%CI)       P(Wald's test) P(LR-test)
volo_1: 1 vs 0   1.84 (1.13,3)         0.72 (0.42,1.24)     0.24           0.232     
                                                                                     
RTS_cat2: 1 vs 0 74.68 (41.26,135.18)  78.49 (43.12,142.9)  < 0.001        < 0.001   
                                                                                     
Log-likelihood = -289.3289
No. of observations = 3143
AIC value = 584.6577


db_rts <- db[ which(db$RTS_cat2==1), ]

> table(db_rts$morto, db_rts$volo_1)
   
      0   1
  0 195  73
  1  74  20
> 
> full.model <- glm(morto ~ volo_1    , data = db_rts,family=binomial())
> logistic.display(full.model)

Logistic regression predicting morto : 1 vs 0 
 
               OR(95%CI)         P(Wald's test) P(LR-test)
volo_1: 1 vs 0 0.72 (0.41,1.27)  0.256          0.249     
                                                          
Log-likelihood = -206.6552
No. of observations = 362
AIC value = 417.3104

db_rts1 <- db[ which(db$RTS_cat2==0), ]

> table(db_rts1$morto, db_rts1$volo_1)
   
       0    1
  0 2485  283
  1   12    1
> 
> full.model <- glm(morto ~ volo_1    , data = db_rts1,family=binomial())
> logistic.display(full.model)

Logistic regression predicting morto 
 
               OR(95%CI)         P(Wald's test) P(LR-test)
volo_1: 1 vs 0 0.73 (0.09,5.65)  0.765          0.754     
                                                          
Log-likelihood = -82.6736
No. of observations = 2781
AIC value = 169.3472



I'm not sure, but this sounds like an example of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox, where the slope of a subset has a different slope (in fact different sign) than the global scope. It's arguably not really a paradox but rather a common observation when you have confounding variables like RTS_cat2.

@JonSpring Thank you so much!!! I really think it's the Simpson's paradox!! I didn't know this! I'll look for a regression that works!

@JonSpring, this Is a paradox as clearly said in the link that yourself suggest. Indeed a paradox Is an apparent contradiction not a true one.


How can it be? How can I handle this?

Let's talk about confounding (of which Simpson's Paradox is a flavor).
Let's consider a similar example to yours.  Consider observational data about a drug that prevents death.  We have data on those who took the drug, the sex of the patient, and their outcome.
In short:

Sex causes the decision to take the drug (remember, this is observational data)
The drug causes risk of death to change, and
Sex causes risk of death to change

Let's take a look at some data.

Note:

In each strata defined by sex, the drug has a protective effect (i.e. the odds ratio is less than 1).
However, in total the drug appears to increase the risk of death (the odds ratio is greater than 1).

This is similar to what is happening in your data.  But what exactly is happening?  Let's first discuss the right way to analyze these data.  We will discover that the drug actually decreases risk of death (indeed, that is what I simulated it to do).  Then, we will discuss why this paradox occurs.
The Right Analysis
Sex is a confounder for the effect of drug on death.  This means it is a cause of both choosing to take the drug and dying.  From the the data above, you can clearly see that men prefer to take the drug, and by a large amount.
Because sex is a confounder, a stratified analysis is best.  We will analyze the odds ratios in each strata and then perform a weighted average (according to observed weight between men and women).
In R, this can be performed in the following way.  I use fisher.test to estimate the odds ratio (no hypothesis test is performed) and then combine the estimates using weighted.mean.
# Imagine my data is in a dataset called dpretty
ORs <- xtabs(~y+drug + is_male, data=dpretty) %>% 
       apply(., 3, fisher.test) %>% 
       map_dbl('estimate')

weights <- xtabs(~is_male, data=dpretty) %>% 
           prop.table()

weighted.mean(ORs, weights)
[1] 0.7532687

This is close to the true odds ratio of 0.58 from my simulation.  Were a proper sample size calculation to be done, we would likely correctly conclude that the drug prevents death.
Explaining the Paradox
Judea Pearl talks about this paradox in his book "The Book of Why".  In essence, Simpson's paradox is a numerical fact about how fractions work.
Consider each of the 2 2x2 tables above, and label their cells as




Drig
No Drug




Dead
$a_i$
$b_i$


Alive
$c_i$
$d_i$



The paradox arises because we expect if the strata ORs $ (a_i d_i) / (b_i  c_i)$ are all smaller than 1, then the marginal OR will be less than 1 too.  That just isn't how fractions work.
From the process I describe, we can actually demonstrate that ignoring the strata will lead to the wrong answer.  Let's do that now.
First, we need to understand how these data were simulated.  In R...
set.seed(0)
n <- 1000
is_male <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)
drug <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.6 + 0.3*is_male)
y <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.4 - 0.1*drug + 0.4*is_male)

I first set the seed for reproducibility, then I simulate binary indicators for sex, $S$ (1 for male, 0 for female).  These are in turn used to determine drug exposure, $D$, with exposure probability $$P(D \mid S=s) = 0.6 + 0.3S$$.  So men are more likely to take the drug.  This comports with what we see above.
Next, the risk of death, $Y$, is a function of both sex and drug status.  The risk of death is
$$ P(Y \mid D, S) = 0.4 -0.1D + 0.4S $$
The drug in reality has a protective effect; it reduces the risk of death by 10% for both men and women. However, men are more likely to die, and so because men are also more likely to take the drug, this can make it appear as if the drug is increasing risk of death when in reality the difference is explained by sex.
Given this information you could go ahead and compute the probability of death conditioned on drug ignoring sex.  You do that by computing
$$ P(Y\mid D) = \sum_S P(Y\mid S, D) P(S \mid D)  $$
This weights within strata estimates by the wrong weight ($P(S\mid D)$ as instead of $P(S)$).  As a point of interest, not that $P(S\mid D) = P(D \mid S) P(S)$ which is a function of what is called the 'propensity score'.  So the weights we use in the simple difference in means here are almost correct and just need to be adjusted by the inverse of $P(D \mid S)$, which leads to weighting methods.
Anyway, when you compute each probability, it should make it seem like the drug is increasing the risk of death.  The probability of death given the drug should be close to 0.54, and the probability of death without the drug should be 0.48.  Since risk of death is greater in the drug group, it will have an odds ratio larger than 1.  Here is how to do that in R
library(tidyverse)

# Genuine confounding example.  Sex confounds relationship between drug and death

set.seed(0)
n <- 1000000
s <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)
d <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.6 + 0.3*s)
y <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.4 - 0.1*d + 0.4*s)
grid <- tibble(d, s, y)


# Marginal -- confounded -- estimate
# Drug appears to increase risk of death
grid %>% 
  group_by(d) %>% 
  summarise(
    risk_of_death = mean(y)
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>       d risk_of_death
#>   <int>         <dbl>
#> 1     0         0.481
#> 2     1         0.540

outcome <- glm(y ~ s*d, data=grid, family = binomial())
conditional <-glm(s ~ d, data=grid, family = binomial())

modelr::data_grid(grid, s, d) %>% 
  modelr::add_predictions(outcome, var='y_given_s_d', type='response') %>% 
  modelr::add_predictions(conditional, var='s_given_d', type='response') %>% 
  mutate(
    s_given_d = if_else(s==0, 1-s_given_d, s_given_d),
    prod = y_given_s_d * s_given_d
  ) %>% 
  group_by(d) %>% 
  summarise(sum(prod))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>       d `sum(prod)`
#>   <int>       <dbl>
#> 1     0       0.481
#> 2     1       0.540

Created on 2024-04-13 with reprex v2.0.2

I didn't know this! I'll look for a regression that works!

Logistic regression is fine for this, but you need to do some non-data work to determine what answer is "right".  I'm not sure what volo_1 and RTS_cat2 are, but if they are anything like sex and drug in my example then your logistic regression which adjusts for both is fine (though a model with an interaction might be better if you suspect the odds ratio is different within strata).
To be clear this is not a statistical problem, this is a domain knowledge problem we approach with statistics.  You need to think about what you're doing because statistics alone will not tell you which approach is right or wrong, much like statistics could not tell us if the drug made risk of death better or worse in my example.

Thank you @demetri-pananos!!!! I'm not sure volo_1 (night/day air ambulance flight) and RTS_cat2 (revised trauma score dichotomized around 7) are like sex and drug as sex causes the decision to take the drug and this's not for volo_1 and RTS_cat2 that are totally independent. My goal is to demonstrate that the complete database result is the correct one. Instead, it would seem that the correct one is the stratified result. Is there a way to reach my goal in a correct way? Thank you again!

@ArTu the “correct analysis” is not necessarily the stratified one. You need to think about how your variables intersect in a causal sense (if that is what you’re after). Might I suggest drawing a DAG?

Could you tell us what exactly it is you’re studying? Maybe that will help us determine which approach to take. From your description of the variables, I imagine that the trauma score may be a cause of air ambulance flight.

@ArTu I don't think your goal should be do demonstrate anything, your goal should be to investigate the association else you've just trying to use the data to prove something you've already concluded.  Do you have more variables than what you're shared here?  It might be best to open a new question with your proposed research question and the data available to you.  I'd happily provide another answer to that if you could also share part if your data.

I have a database of the interventions carried out by the air ambulance. The H0 is that night flights are more associated with deaths than daytime flights, considering some independent variables such as age, sex, trauma scores, patients’ severity indicators, and on-site maneuvers (intubation, thoracotomy, etc.). In the univariate analysis on the complete db, night flying is more associated with death. This result is also obtained in the analysis adjusted for some variables (age, sex, some maneuvers) but not for others (trauma and severity scores and some maneuvers). @demetri-pananos

My goal is to demonstrate that night flights are more serious and more associated with death for all variables of interest. Thank you for your precious help and your interest @demetri-pananos

I don't think analysis with too many variables is adequate for a post. For sure the objective is to investigate the data, but clinicians hope to confirm the H0 and some of the variables considered do so. The problem is that some of the variables confirm H0 and some do not. @demetri-pananos

@ArTu Ok well then I feel like I have contributed as much as I can here.  I've explained why this apparent change in effect direction can occur -- it is a numerical fact of how fractions work -- and have proposed that to determine the best analysis you will need to think about what variables cause what.  If you found this answer helpful for your original query, please consider accepting it.

This is an example of the Yule Simpson effect (also referred to as paradox).
You can consider your data in two different tables and note that the case of RTS_cat2=0 has much less deceased cases (around 0.4%) than the case of RTS_cat2=1 (around 25%). So when you combine the two tables, then the severe cases of RTS_cat2=1 can be seen as being diluted by the mild cases of RTS_cat2=0. If the degree of mixing is different for the different volo cases, because they occur in different amounts among the RTS_cat2 groups, then this will influence the pattern.
You can compute the total percentage as a weighted average of the percentages in the two cases.
$$p_\text{total} = \frac{n_A}{n_A+n_B} p_A +  \frac{n_B}{n_A+n_B} p_B$$
Then you get:
$$p_{volo=0} = \frac{2479}{2786} 0.48 +  \frac{289}{2786} 26.61 $$
$$p_{volo=1} = \frac{284}{377} 0.40 +  \frac{93}{377} 21.51 $$
The $p_{volo=1}$ computation has smaller terms that are averaged $0.40$ and $21.51$. But, because the weight for the severe percentage is much higher $\frac{93}{377}>\frac{289}{2786}$ you end up with a higher total.

The two tables
$$\begin{array}{}
\rlap{\text{RTS_cat2}=0}\\\\
&\text{volo}=0&\text{volo}=1\\
\text{patients}&2497&284\\
\text{deceased}&12&1\\
\% & 0.48 & 0.40\\
&\,
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{}
\rlap{\text{RTS_cat2}=1}\\\\
&\text{volo}=0&\text{volo}=1\\
\text{patients}&289&93\\
\text{deceased}&74&20 \\
\% & 26.61 & 21.51
\end{array}$$

Thank you @sextus-empiricus! So is it correct to conclude that flight=0 is more associated with death than flight=1? But what if the goal was to prove the opposite? since RTS (revised trauma score) is just one of the independent variables I need to consider in my analysis.

I have a db of the air ambulance interventions. The H0 is that night flights are more associated with deaths than daytime flights, considering some independent variables such as age, sex, trauma scores (like RTS), patients’ severity indicators, and on-site maneuvers (intubation, thoracotomy, etc.). In the univariate analysis on the complete db, night flying is more associated with death. This result is also obtained in the analysis adjusted for some variables (age, sex, some maneuvers) but not for others (trauma and severity scores and some maneuvers). @sextus-empiricus

My goal is to be able to demonstrate that night flights are more serious and more associated with death for all variables of interest, not just for some.@sextus-empiricus Thank you for your precious help and your interest!

The context is very important. I believe there is a specific name for the reverse of the Yule Simpson effect and the situation where people look at the effect conditional on sub populations whereas they should be looking at the marginal effect. So if the case is like 'volo' being a variable for the type of accident and 'RTS' a type of trauma, then you should look at the total margin. The difference is whether RTS is caused by volo or independent from volo.

A problem is that daytime/nighttime may not be so much independent from trauma. You have a large difference in the number of day and night flights. Possibly during the day more easy flights for non-trauma cases are performed (diluting effect)? So yes night flights are more serious, due to mild cases missing out, but conditional on that seriousness the deaths are not higher. It is probably not like flying during the night causes more difficult cases and more death (that's what I thought for a while, that difficult flying circumstances cause more deaths)

I don't think there is a dilution effect. The criteria for night and day flights are the same. The numbers are different as domestic, sporting, and work accidents are rarer at night than during the day. We observe just road accidents. I verified the absence of collinearity by calculating the VIF and found no correlations between all the independent variables of interest. @sextus-empiricus

the problem is that adjusting death ~ flight for some variables we observe a higher mortality for night flights (as an unadjusted regression on the complete database), while adjusting for other variables we observe a higher mortality for daytime flights. how to solve this problem? @sextus-empiricus

@ArTu I don't see so much the problem. The solution of the problem might be to stop seeing it as a problem. You have two clear patterns, why are they bad? 1) At night you have relative less helicopters going out for less severe cases (which are more typical to daily activities), and as a consequence you have a higher fraction of severe cases and mortality. 2) When you consider these differences conditional on the type of cases then the night flight seem less bad. (but the difference is not very significant and you can also consider it as equally bad)

I finally made peace with the idea of having two patterns and that's okay. Probably the "true" pattern is the one obtained by stratifying as I understood that the variables that determine that daytime flights are more associated with mortality are the variables relating to the clinical severity of the patient that are fundamental for framing the situation. Than you so so much for your help! It was very helpful and educational!@sextus-empiricus
